# how to add Additional information to the android ui element

Tags: java, android, accessibility

I'd like to     add to android widget more detailed description I.E I need an alternative to the HTML attribute aria-describedby for android.
e.G. I want to TB  announces exit button with additional description as "exit button press to close application", here "exit" i added by contentdescription

```
button.setContentDescription("exit");
```

but how can  i add more details: "press to close application"?

Comment: For understanding: You want the TalkBack-reader to read "Exit, Button ... Double-tap to activate ... Press to close application"? Or do yo want "Exit, Button ... Press to close application"? If you want the latter, my answer still is valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer:** You should not.

---

**Longer answer:** You should not because this can become pretty confusing for the user.

**Reason 1:**

Under "Settings -> Accessibility -> TalkBack -> Settings -> Verbosity" the user can decide to not let TalkBack read the element type.
Then your content description would not be read as "Exit, Button ... Double-tap to activate" but instead as "Exit".
So the information you have put into the second part is lost for the user.

**Reason 2:**

Depending on your target group the user might not even physically interact with your screen. Some users might use the voice-input or a switch-box as a proxy between them and the screen. TalkBack saying "Press" simply would be wrong or even confusing for the user, since they will never press anything on the screen.

Therefore Google has decided to use more generic terms and sentences, which you should keep using as well.

**Reason 3:**

A handicapped person that uses the TalkBack-reader a lot is used to much faster reading-speeds and they are used to the standard OS-elements. If you start to rename them, their usual flow gets interrupted and the user gets confused:

```
"ABC-Button ... Double-tap to activate"
"DEF-Button ... Double-tap to activate"
"GHI-Button ... Double-tap to activate"
"JKL-Button ... Press to close application" ... "Huh?!"
"MNO-Button ... Double-tap to activate"
```

**Possible solution:**

Do not give handicapped user (much) more information than a seeing user. Your elements should "speak for themselves" by having a generic but understandable description for seeing and non-seeing users.

If the user can deduce from the context that the button will close the application, then the text "Exit" on the button is sufficient.

Else you could name your button "Exit application", which will be the same text for the content description.

Comment: Text: "press to close application" is just example. I need alternative for aria-describedby and i think that alternative is SetRoleDescription().

Comment: From the Android Developer-site for `setRoleDescription()`: `Warning: For consistency with other applications, you should not use the role description to force accessibility services to describe standard views (such as buttons ...) using specific wording.`

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.html#setRoleDescription(java.lang.CharSequence)